# Windows: what is the group of icons by the clock called?

Tags: windows

Getting my terms confused here:

The "taskbar" is the entire bar with the launcher, program icons, clock, show-desktop-button and little group of icons called the....

[image]

Comment: You mean the system tray?

Comment: That's it.  Make it an answer and ill give you the easy points :p

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is your "Notification Area" or "System Tray".

More info from [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aiat.html):

> The **system tray** is located in the Windows Taskbar, usually at the
>   bottom right corner next to the clock. It contains miniature icons for
>   easy access to system functions such as antivirus settings, printer,
>   modem, sound volume, battery status, and more.

And from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Taskbar_elements):

> The **notification area** is the portion of the taskbar that displays
>   icons for system and program features that have no presence on the
>   desktop as well as the time and the volume icon. It contains mainly
>   icons that show status information, though some programs, such as
>   Winamp, use it for minimized windows...  *The notification area is commonly referred to as the system tray, which Microsoft states is wrong*, although the term is sometimes used in Microsoft documentation, articles, and software descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Your system tray look different than mine, because your taskbar is placed on the right. But I am quite confident that you are searching for the term "system tray".